# Include ou Require no Nodejs para separar códigos

Tags: node.js, sintaxe, include

Olá! gostaria de saber se no nodejs é possível separar alguns códigos em arquivos diferentes conforme este exemplo abaixo, e como fazer isso:

Atualmente tenho apenas um arquivo dessa forma:

**Arquivo 111.js**

```
var app     = require('../app');
var debug   = require('debug')('cancela:server');
var http    = require('http');
var b       = require('../config/gpio');
const bbbio = require('../config/bbb-io');

// Códigos iniciais
//...
//...

        var server = http.createServer(app);

        // Códigos para serem separados em outro arquivo

        var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
        io.on('connection', function (socket) {
            socket.on('changeState', handleChangeState);
        });

        function handleChangeState(data) {
            var newData = JSON.parse(data);
            b.digitalWrite(bbbio.controleCancela, newData.state);
        }

// Outros códigos
//...
//...
```

Criando um arquivo adicional "functions.js"

**functions.js**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('changeState', handleChangeState);
});

function handleChangeState(data) {
    var newData = JSON.parse(data);
    b.digitalWrite(bbbio.controleCancela, newData.state);
}
```

E incluindo "functions.js" em "111.js" para ficar algo como abaixo, mas não estou conseguindo encontrar a maneira certa de fazer o "include" ou "require":

**111.js** já atualizado:

```
Arquivo 111.js 
var app     = require('../app');
var debug   = require('debug')('cancela:server');
var http    = require('http');
var b       = require('../config/gpio');
const bbbio = require('../config/bbb-io');

// Códigos iniciais
//...
//...
        var server = http.createServer(app);

        require('./functions');  <<<=== APENAS INCLUIR O CONTEÚDO DO ARQUIVO functions.js, SUBSTITUINDO O CÓDIGO ANTERIOR, MAIS NADA

// Outros códigos
//...
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

A parte dos `requires` está correta, mas dentro de cada módulo você precisa exportar as partes que vão ser públicas. Por exemplo:

**arquivo1.js**

```
function funcao() {

}
exports.funcao = funcao;
```

**arquivo2.js**

```
var funcoes = require('./arquivo1.js');
funcoes.funcao();
```

Este artigo dá mais detalhes: http://nodebr.com/como-funciona-a-funcao-require-do-node-js/

Answer (score 0):

Com ES6 a sintaxe é diferente e pode fornecer algumas outras funcionalidades, como a importação ser assíncrona e poder importar somente partes que são necessárias.

### Sintaxe

*foobar.js*

```
export function foo() {
  return 'bar';
}
export function bar() {
  return 'foo';
}
```

*main.js*

```
import {foo, bar} from 'foobar';
console.log(foo());
console.log(bar());
```

Comment: Lucas e @NotMe, obrigado. Acabei não comentando ,mas eu já tinha verificado a documentação além de outros posts do pessoal e encontrei essas funcionalidades. O que eu gostaria mesmo é que o código fosse substituído, literalmente, do conteúdo do arquivo separado `foobar.js` para dentro do `main.js`, para não precisar fazer a chamada das funções exportadas tal como em `console.log(bar());`.Seria o equivalente ao que um "DEFINE" faz em "linguagem C". É possível isso no Nodejs ou estou viajando?

Comment: @wBB não dá, o método no node é require + module.exports. O sistema de módulos foi concebido assim, para não vazar nada pro escopo global.